# how to copy contents of one slice to another slice in go

Tags: go

I'm doing below exercise in go.

**Create a slice with four elements. Create a new slice and copy the third
and fourth elements only into it.**

I have return the below program

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        var elements = make([]string, 4)
        elements[0] = "1"
        elements[1] = "2"
        elements[2] = "3"
        elements[3] = "4"
        fmt.Println(elements)

        var newElements = make([]string, 2)
        newElements = append(elements[:0], elements[:2]...)
        fmt.Println(newElements)
    }
```

output of my program is. But I want the newElements slice to be [3 4]-

```
[1 2 3 4]
[1 2]
```

What is wrong in my program.

Comment: `newElements = append(elements[:0], elements[:2]...) `  typo `elements[:0]` ? it should be `newElements` according to your code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the built-in [copy](https://godoc.org/builtin#copy) function to copy elements from one slice to another.

```
var newElements = make([]string, 2)
copy(newElements, elements[2:])
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i5g2dU7bW6g)

Use [slices.Clone](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Clone) to create the slice and copy the elements in a single statement:

```
newElements := slices.Clone(elements[2:])
```

[Run it on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-y3RkMvi63M)

In versions of Go before 1.21, use append to create the slice and copy the elements in a single statement:

```
newElements := append([]string(nil), elements[2:4]...)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XE1srsVe3d2).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in the line `newElements = append(elements[:0], elements[:2]...)`. Here `elements[:2]` means elements `elements[0]`, `elements[1]`. That's why your output is `[1,2]`. For third and fourth elements use this `elements[2:4]`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var elements = make([]string, 4)
    elements[0] = "1"
    elements[1] = "2"
    elements[2] = "3"
    elements[3] = "4"
    fmt.Println(elements)

    var newElements = make([]string, 2)
    newElements = append(elements[:0], elements[2:4]...)
    fmt.Println(newElements)
}
```